# Generate a irregular sequence of numbers based on a vector of intervals in R

Tags: r, sequence, intervals

I want to create a sequence of numbers from -100 to 100 by a vector specifying  different intervals.

```
start<- -100
end <- 100
intervals <- c(10,5,100,4)

output:
-100, -90, -85, 15, 19, 100
```

Comment: Use `seq(-100, 100, 10)` and substitute `10` with the number you want between one number and another.

Comment: @SabDeM I get an error when i substitute 10 with an vector of irregular decimals.

Comment: Update your question and specify what kind of intervals do you want, it is better that you provide a desired output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
c(start + cumsum(c(0, intervals)), end)
# [1] -100  -90  -85   15   19  100
```

Then "end" is just tacked on the end. You can do something else with it, but you'll have to decide what would happen in the case your intervals go over it.

Also note that your stated requirement,

> I want the length of my sequence to be same length as the interval vector.

is contradicted by your desired output. If you want different behavior, you'll need to be more precise.